# Can I protect a file from being copied off my flash drive?

Tags: permissions, filesystems, usb-flash-drive

I have one flashdrive that contains serveral files type. (.mp3, .doc, .bnl)

I need to protect another user to **copy file .bnl** out of my flashdrive. They just look and open only. For other file types, copying is allowed.

Can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

If you can read it, you can copy it.  What you describe cannot be done unless you control the machine they are using to read your drive.  Even if you did, you'd have to stop him from snapping photos of the monitor.

Answer (score 2):

There are programs you can control the read/write function of a file with copy prevention features too.

Secudrive has a few programs that can make the files so that they can't be copied out and can be set to read-only. They have Content Guard which is like a manager program that you can use for multiple USBs, and USB Office/CAD which are both copy protected USBs that work for Office programs (such as MS Word, Excel, etc.) or CAD files. Here's a link to the page: http://www.secudrives.com